# Hibernate 6.3.1.Final Mariadb @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING) not working

Tags: hibernate, enums, spring-boot-starter

Using a legacy db schema with newest Hibernate 6.3.1.Final with Spring Boot 3.1.4 has had quite a few code migration work needed for JPA models.  Most of my issues currently are with Enum types.  I've had issue with Enums in the mysql database that were stored as int(11) producing "expecting #TINYINT" errors, which I could only solve by changing the column type in the db (something that would break legacy code).  I tried these changes to the annotation to no avail, and I couldn't find any other solution in blogs.  Note: I did not have these validation issues with Hibernate 6.0.1.Final:

@Column(name="status", columnDefinition = "INTEGER")
or
@Column(name="status", columnDefinition = "int2")

Another issue was with "@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)", which doesn't seem to work at all. Documentation from https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.3/introduction/html_single/Hibernate_Introduction.html#enums isn't complete or no longer accurate.  I have an enum in a legacy database stored as "varchar(255)", with the following JPA definition:

```
@Column(name = "status", nullable = false)
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@Basic(optional=false)
private ActiveOrInactive status;
```

And I get the following error on validation:

found [varchar (Types#VARCHAR)], but expecting [enum ('active','inactive') (Types#ENUM)]

Again, I did not get this issue with Hibernate 6.0.1.Final.

What changes should I make to my annotation for Enums stored as int(11) or varchar(255) in Mysql db?

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public enum ActiveOrInactive {
    
    Active, Inactive;
    
    static final Map<String, ActiveOrInactive> _activeOrInactive = new HashMap<String, ActiveOrInactive>();
    static {
        for (ActiveOrInactive activeOrInactive : ActiveOrInactive.values()) {
            _activeOrInactive.put(activeOrInactive.toString(), activeOrInactive);
        }
    }
    
    public static Map<String, ActiveOrInactive> getPublishedStateTypes() {
        return _activeOrInactive;
    }
    

}
```

Comment: You probably need to declare them as int and string in your ORM.

Comment: As mentioned, this is a legacy database with other legacy applications still using it.  The original design is over 20 years old, and changing the schema is kind of a last resort.   I guess I'm trying to understand why moving from 6.0.1.Final, where it was working fine, is no longer supporting this code.  What changes are necessary with the annotations?  I can't find any documentation for that.

Comment: I did find that major updates were made from 6.0 to 6.1 to the schema validation was done, and there were issues in 6.1 - 6.2 with some of the OneToMany mappedBy constructs, and I found they were cleared up with 6.3.1, but now I have to override maven spring boot 3.1 build with hibernate 6.0 to get by this Enum situation.

Comment: I added the Enum class code block above.  As this is a Spring Boot JPA appilcation, there is no XML ORM mapping file, everything is with annotations, or I am not understanding what you mean by modifying the ORM.  The above annotated Spring Boot 3.1 configurations work, but only with Hibernate 6.0.2.Final and below.  My question is, why doesn't it work with the latest Hibernate 6.3.1.Final?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.3/introduction/html_single/Hibernate_Introduction.html
`@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)` is mapped to varchar, except for Mysql (and maybe MariaDB) where it is mapped to an ENUM column type.

If you change:
`@Column(name = "status", nullable = false)`
to:

`@Column(name = "status", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "varchar")`

you can make hibernate understand that it's a varchar column.

Comment: Though the CustomConverter may have worked, using columnDefinition="varchar" was a much simpler solution.  This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should use a Custom Converter for this.
I am giving an example for `datatype` `varchar` in your database i.e., `@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)`, if it is for `int`, changes in your custom converter class can be made accordingly.

```
@Converter
public class ActiveOrInactiveConverter implements Serializable,  AttributeConverter<ActiveOrInactive, String> {

    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(ActiveOrInactive attribute) {
        if (attribute == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return attribute.name();
    }

    @Override
    public ActiveOrInactive convertToEntityAttribute(String dbData) {
        if (dbData == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return ActiveOrInactive.valueOf(dbData);
    }
}
```

And

You should replace your

```
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
```

with

```
@Convert(converter = ActiveOrInactiveConverter.class)
```

It should look like:

```
@Column(name = "status", nullable = false)
@Convert(converter = ActiveOrInactiveConverter.class)
@Basic(optional=false)
private ActiveOrInactive status;
```

Here is a [reference](https://thorben-janssen.com/hibernate-enum-mappings/)